# MDYY SQL Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime-format

Is there a way to format a sql date like this:

3/11/2009 (as opposed to03/11/2009)

20/7/2008 (as opposed to 20/07/2008)

Thanks!

Comment: where are you looking at the results? (report, application, t-sql editor?)

Answer (score 2):

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy
```

See the set dateformat docs : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL itself, you can look in Books Online about the `CONVERT` keyword. It shows a list of codes that give different date formats.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this UDF..**

```
create function dbo.mdyDate(@theDate DATETIME,@fmt INT) 
returns VARCHAR(10) 
as 
BEGIN
    declare   @ans   VARCHAR(10)
    set @ans = replace(convert(varchar(10),@theDate,@OptFmt),'/0','/') 
    if left(@ans,1)='0' set @ans=substring(@ans,2,9)
    return @ans
END
```

**Examples**

```
select dbo.mdyDate( dateadd(d,-10,getDate()),103 )      --  Nov 4, 2009
select dbo.mdyDate( dateadd(m,-5,getDate()),103 )       --  June 14, 2009
select dbo.mdyDate( dateadd(d,-10,getDate()),101 )      --  Nov 4, 2009
select dbo.mdyDate( dateadd(m,-5,getDate()),101 )       --  June 14, 2009
```